# How convert own class to another own class

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a method to convert my own class to my another own class using flutter extension. As you can see I tried to make a method `toBird`. But I have no idea with. I hope I can make method similar to `toInt()`, `toDouble()`, or `toString()`.

i tried:

```
class Fish {
  int speed; 
  Fish(this.speed)
}

class Bird  {
  double damage;
  Bird(this.damage);
}

extension FishExtension on Fish{
  Bird get toBird=> Bird(this);
}

void main() {
  Fish barracuda= Fish(10);
  Bird eagle= barracuda.toBird; 
  print(eagle);
}
```

is it possible to cast type using own class type  ??

Thank you, I hope someone can help and teach me how to do this.

[image]

**Edit:** i add some class variable to avoid being ambiguous.

I deliberately left blank, because maybe someone would think to directly convert the value in the class. But what I want is to convert that class

Comment: Your dart pad doesn't contain the code. Please add the correct dart link with your code. And we appreciate adding a code snippet rather than having screenshots of your code. Please use snippet like this to copy your code: ```Your code goes here```.

Comment: There is no *automatic* conversion of one type to another. Your code is fine, except that you have to call the `Bird` constructor with a *valid value*, and a `Fish` is not a valid value. *You* have to figure out what that valid value is, and if there is no logical answer (like here, because a fish has no bird damage), the conversion most likely does not make sense to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a "working" code:

```
class Fish{}

class Bird{}

extension FishExtension on Fish {
  Bird get toBird => Bird();
}

void main() {
  Fish barracuda = Fish();
  Bird eagle = barracuda.toBird;
  print(eagle);
}
```

I'm not sure what your goal is and why do you need to convert a fish to a bird. But the error message is straightforward. You've tried to create an instance of bird class with a parameterless constructor passing an instance of a fish class.

As a result, the `toBird` method does nothing. It just creates a fresh new instance of bird class. There is no any kind of conversion here. Fish class hasn't any data (no fields), as a result, no real (useful) conversion possible here.

**Update**:

```
class Fish {
  int speed; 
  Fish(this.speed);
}

class Bird  {
  double damage;
  Bird(this.damage);
}

extension FishExtension on Fish{
  Bird get toBird => Bird(this.speed.toDouble());
}

void main() {
  Fish barracuda = Fish(10);
  Bird eagle = barracuda.toBird; 
  print("Eagle: $eagle, eagle damage: ${eagle.damage}"); // Eagle: Instance of 'Bird', eagle damage: 10
}
```

Comment: i trying to make methods that working like `toInt` or another similar. The Fish and Bird just my practice code. Don't know if this is possible right. indeed there is no point in this conversion, but I can use it for other things

Comment: @AlfhaOmega Try the code above, maybe it's enough for your needs.

Comment: not yet, I'm still looking for equivalent conversions like: 
`int a = 10, String b = a.toString ();` which is where the value `10` has been converted

Comment: @AlfhaOmega the code above just the same, no? `Fish a = Fish(); Bird b = a.toBird;` Or you are talking about braces difference? Or what?

Comment: your `a.toBird` not contain any Fish value. I have updated adding variables in both classes to avoid ambiguity

Comment: @AlfhaOmega: I've added an example.

Comment: i know when i put some variable into the class, some answer will be convert the value inside the class.